# Django functional Based view to FormView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have my code written in functional-based views and I came to know about the generic views which are built into Django. I have made changes using Views, TemplateViews but I got stuck at FormView.

**Functional Based View:**

```
def NewTeam(request):
    form = NewTeamForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= NewTeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)
            return teams(request)
        else:
            print("Invalid Form")
    return render(request,'teamform.html', {'form':form})
```

**FormView I tried**

```
class NewTeam(FormView):
    template_name = 'teamform.html'
    form_class = NewTeamForm
    success_url = '.'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(NewTeam, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = NewTeamForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form= NewTeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit = True)
                return teams(request)
            else:
                print("Invalid Form")
        context['form'] =form
        return context
```

I can understand that I need to get the context in the first function and create a new function `form_valid`. I have seen the documentation and other stack answers but I couldn't get it like how to validate the form with in it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django FormView automatically calls validation on the form

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class NewTeam(FormView):
    template_name = 'teamform.html'
    form_class = NewTeamForm
    success_url = '.'

def form_valid(self, form):
    # Form is Valid
    new_team = form.save(commit=True)

    # Do whatever

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

def form_invalid(self, form):
    # Form is Invalid
    print(form.errors)

    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```